# C# modify value of XElement in arbitrary nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to modify the value of an element selected by the user. The xml nodes are displayed in a `TreeView` and when the user selects a node its elements are displayed in textboxes. I want to write a method that saves the value of the modified element into the `XDocument`.

Here's the code I tried:

```
private void ElementTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XElement myElement = doc.XPathSelectElement(TView_.SelectedNode.FullPath.Replace("\\", "/"));
    myElement.SetElementValue(XName.Get((sender as TextBox).Tag.ToString()), (sender as TextBox).Text);
    FillTree(doc);
}
```

I have only found answers here that use a fixed xml structure.

Comment: What's your UI? This sounds like a good use case for binding, since your looking for a dynamic structure...

Comment: What are remembering on the [`TreeNode.Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property?  If you remember the `XNode` things will be much easier.

Comment: It turned out that this part of the code is fine. I've accidentally overwritten the XDocument somewhere else.